# Set requestTimeout on a per route basis in Fastify

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

Is it possible to set the request timeout on a per request basis in Fastify?

I am able to set a default request timeout at the the server level (applies to all routes) [see below]

```
const fastify = Fastify({ logger: true, requestTimeout: 1000 });
```

However, every *fastify-ish* attempt doesn't work

**Does not work**

```
async function routes(fastify, options) {
  // or fastify.server.requestTimeout = 1000;
  const opts = {
    requestTimeout: 1000,
    schema: {
      response: {},
    },
    handler: async (req, res) => {
      await setTimeout(2000);
      return { hello: 'world' };
    },
    onTimeout: (req, res) => {
      return res.send({ timed: 'out' });
    },
  };

  fastify.get('/', opts);
}
```

**Does work, but is there a "fastify-ish" solution for this?**

The only solution that appears to work for me seems a bit hackish, going straight to the node http request. I wonder if there's an easier way to do this using Fastify?

```
    fastify.addHook('onRequest', async (req, res) => {
      req.controller = new AbortController();
      req.signal = req.controller.signal;
      res.raw.setTimeout(1000, async () => {
        req.controller.abort();
        res.code(408).send(new Error('Server Timeout'));
      });
      await res;
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution that works for me

#### Set custom timeouts for each request in fastify

```
export const setTimeoutOnRequest = (req, res, timeoutMs = 1000) => {
  req.controller = new AbortController();
  req.signal = req.controller.signal;
  res.raw.setTimeout(timeoutMs, () => {
    req.controller.abort();
    res.code(408).send(new Error('Server Timeout'));
  });
};
```

Can be used as such

```
fastify.get('/init', async (req, res) => {
    setTimeoutOnRequest(req, res, 20000);
        // your code that might cause a timeout
        return {...your response body}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a custom Fastify plugin to handle request timeouts. I'm not entirely sure how robust my solution.

Here's my current implementation:

```
import fp from "fastify-plugin";
import { requestContext } from "@fastify/request-context";

import { SERVER_TIMEOUT_408 } from "#errors";

const TIMEOUT_KEY = "TIMEOUT_KEY";
const CONTROLLER_KEY = "CONTROLLER_KEY";
const SIGNAL_KEY = "SIGNAL_KEY";

/**
 * Plugin to handle request timeout.
 * @example Route-Level Usage
 * fastify.get('/some-route', {
 *   config: {
 *     timeout: 2000 // 2 seconds
 *   }
 * }, async (request, reply) => {
 *   // Your handler logic
 * });
 * @type {import('@fastify/type-provider-typebox').FastifyPluginAsyncTypebox} app
 */
async function requestTimeoutPlugin(app, options) {
  function setupRequestTimeout(req, reply, done) {
    try {
      const controller = new AbortController();
      const signal = controller.signal;

      const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        controller.abort();
        done(new SERVER_TIMEOUT_408());
      }, reply.context.config.timeout ?? options.configs.serverConfig.requestTimeout);

      requestContext.set(TIMEOUT_KEY, timeoutId);
      requestContext.set(CONTROLLER_KEY, controller);
      requestContext.set(SIGNAL_KEY, signal);

      done();
    } catch (error) {
      done(error);
    }
  }

  function cleanupResources() {
    const timeoutId = requestContext.get(TIMEOUT_KEY);
    if (timeoutId) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      requestContext.set(TIMEOUT_KEY, null);
      requestContext.set(CONTROLLER_KEY, null);
      requestContext.set(SIGNAL_KEY, null);
    }
  }

  app.addHook("onRequest", setupRequestTimeout);

  app.addHook("onSend", (req, reply, payload, done) => {
    try {
      cleanupResources();
      done(null, payload);
    } catch (error) {
      done(error);
    }
  });

  app.addHook("onError", (req, reply, error, done) => {
    cleanupResources();
    done(error);
  });
}

export default fp(requestTimeoutPlugin);
```